# How can I bin by date ranges and categories in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a date, a category and a value. I'd like to plot the sum-aggregated values per category. For example I want to sum values which happen in 3 day periods, but for each category individually.

An attempt which seems too complicating is

```
import random
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
random.seed(0)

df=pd.DataFrame([[dt.datetime(2000,1,random.randint(1,31)), random.choice("abc"), random.randint(1,3)] for _ in range(100)], columns=["date", "cat", "value"])
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

result=df.groupby("cat").resample("3d", how="sum").unstack("cat").value.fillna(0)
result.plot()
```

This is basically the right logic, but the resampling doesn't have a fixed start, so the date ranges for the 3-day periods don't align between categories (and I get NaN/0 values).

What is a better way to achieve this plot?

Comment: You can maybe first reindex, so you are sure every category starts at the same date? Further, does it matter what 3-day periods you end up with, as long as they are the same?

Comment: For now they only should be the same. But maybe later I'd like to have more control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should group by `cat` and `date`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[dt.datetime(2000,1,random.randint(1,31)), random.choice("abc"), random.randint(1,3)] for _ in range(100)], columns=["date", "cat", "value"])
df.groupby(["cat", pd.Grouper(freq='3d',key='date')]).sum().unstack(0).fillna(0).plot()
```